# Spring Kafka Errorhandling for batchlisteners

Tags: spring-kafka

We have implemented a batchListener on a certain topic. There we read and process a bunch of records at the same time. If anything goes wrong we cannot detect which record caused the exception. Therefore we are not able to rise a BatchListenerFailedException. According the docs (https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#retrying-batch-eh) the whole batch gets reprocesssed, until the retries are exhausted.

Lets say a certain record contained in this batch caused a NullpointerException during processing. I cannot detect in the recoverer which record caused the problem neither.

Is there any solution to this kind of problem? In my eyes it would be very helpful if one could process record-by-record in cases an exception occurred.

Answer (score 1):

We cannot switch between batch and record listeners when an exception occurs.

See the documentation for how to handle this use case.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#default-eh

Use

```java
@KafkaListener(id = "recovering", topics = "someTopic")
public void listen(List<Thing> things) {
    for (int i = 0; i < records.size(); i++) {
        try {
            process(things.get(i));
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            throw new BatchListenerFailedException("Failed to process", e, i);
        }
    }
}
```

or

```java
@KafkaListener(id = "recovering", topics = "someTopic")
public void listen(<ConsumerRecord<String, Thing> records) {
    things.forEach(record ->
        try {
            process(record);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            throw new BatchListenerFailedException("Failed to process", e, record);
        }
    }
}
```

This will work (in 2.8.x) with the `DefaultErrorHandler` (which is the default). For earlier versions, it requires the `RecoveringBatchErrorHandler`.